# Issue with overflow and width

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a container that have a bunch of `<a>` tags and they are all inside a container that have 465px in width. that container is named `AssetBrowsercolumn-right` and is inside in container that have `overflow-y auto` and a width of 760px that is named `Container`.  `Container` have also `AssetBrowsercolumn-right`.

The problem I have is that when the scrollbar is visible the width of the `AssetBrowsercolumn-right` is correct but when the scrollbar is not displayed there is a space. I cant figure out a way to fix this. Beacuse if I add 15px to the `AssetBrowsercolumn-right` the space is gone but then when the scrollbar is displayed it gets messed up..

it seems that when scrollbar is visible it adds 10-20px. and when its not displayed 10-20px is removed.

Is there any good fix for this?

```
#container{
height:500px;
width: 760px;
overflow-y:auto;
}


.assetbrowserColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;

}

.assetbrowsercolumn-right {
    float: right;
    width:465px;
}

.link-items {
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
display:block;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 34px;
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/529UE/1/)

Remove some A tags that are inside `assetbrowserColumn` in the jsfiddle to see what I mean.

Comment: Fiddle would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle would be helpfull, but you could try this:

```
.assetbrowsercolumn-right {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:480px;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can set dynamic width like this to solve it:

```
.assetbrowsercolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
   border: 0px solid black;
}

.assetbrowsercolumn-right {
    float: right;
    width:65%;
       border: 0px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Its not working still space, check my jsfiddle thats how I want it to look all the time even if scrollbar is displayed or not. But try to remove some A tags and see what I mean.

Comment: Took a look at the fiddle you provided, can you solve it with dynamic width (see edit)?

Comment: Did you remove the borders?

Comment: can you tell me which browser you use?